# How to disable TextFormField default animation

Tags: flutter

I want to disable the default behavior when a user focus on the text field, where the label text gets smaller and docks to the upper left : [image: textform field]

I want to disable this behavior and only make the label text disappear, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

Use `FloatingLabelBehavior.never` inside `InputDecoration` will help you hiding your label and instead of `labelText` you can use `hintText` so it becomes disappear when you type something.

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Search",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        suffixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: This is the answer that is best to use when wanting to have a custom TextFormField component without the animation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this

```
TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                  hintText: "Hints"),
            )
And customize textfield decoration as you desired.
```

Comment: But how can I make the hintText disappear when the field is focused?

Comment: when you type automatically disappear

Comment: It doesn't disappear for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually add a leading widget inside TextFormField where you can put the country picker.

```
  Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: FormBuilderTextField(
                  validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                    FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
                    FormBuilderValidators.minLength(context, 9),
                    FormBuilderValidators.maxLength(context, 9),
                    FormBuilderValidators.numeric(context),
                  ]),
                  name: "mobile_number",
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: CountryPickerDropdown(
                        initialValue: 'AU',
                        itemBuilder: _buildDropdownItem,
                        itemFilter: (c) => [
                          'AU',
                          'PH',
                        ].contains(c.isoCode),
                        priorityList: [
                          CountryPickerUtils.getCountryByIsoCode('AU'),
                          CountryPickerUtils.getCountryByIsoCode('PH'),
                        ],
                        sortComparator: (Country a, Country b) =>
                            a.isoCode.compareTo(b.isoCode),
                        onValuePicked: (Country country) {
                          print("${country}");
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Mobile #',
                    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            ),
```